# How to sort array having duplicate keys and values and show all keys and values respectively including duplicates from array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, duplicates, ksort

I am having an issue showing all keys to their respective values while I am shorting this array in php.

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43", "Ben"=>"56");
ksort ($age);
foreach($age as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
}
```

The result I am getting is

```
Key=Ben, Value=56
Key=Joe, Value=43
Key=Peter, Value=35
```

The result should be

```
Key=Ben, Value=37
Key=Ben, Value=56
Key=Joe, Value=43
Key=Peter, Value=35
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple keys with the same "name".

It has to be possible to fetch a value by a unique key. Having the same key twice would give problems.

You can instead use a numeric array with sub-arrays to get around this:

```
[
 ['name' => 'Peter', 'age' => 35],
 ['name' => 'Ben', 'age' => 37],
 ['name' => 'Ben', 'age' => 56],
];
```

Your code adjusted:

```
$age = [
 ['name' => 'Peter', 'age' => 35],
 ['name' => 'Ben', 'age' => 37],
 ['name' => 'Ben', 'age' => 56],
 ['name' => 'Joe', 'age' => 43],
];

usort($age, function ($a, $b) {
    return $age['age'] - $b['age'];
});

foreach($age as $key => $person) {
    echo "Name=" . $person['name'] . ", Age=". $person['age'];
}
```

Comment: Could you please write full code for this, I am having not much experience with php.

Comment: I have updated my answer, @LovekushNiranjan. I have not tested it. But it uses the usort() function to sort by a value in the sub-arrays.

Comment: I want to sort the array by keys not by the values, @xyz

Comment: simply change the array key used in the usort from `return $age['age'] - $b['age'];` to `return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);`

Comment: getting same result after this "return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);" @xyz